# Accessing SimpleButton TextField

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've been trying to change the text within a SimpleButton instance using this:

```
var drawButton:SimpleButton = main.drawButton;
var upButton:DisplayObjectContainer = drawButton.upState as DisplayObjectContainer;
var upButtonText:TextField = upButton.getChildAt(1) as TextField;
upButtonText.text = "Pause";
```

I found this solution from here: [how can i change texts in the dynamic textFields in SimpleButton instance (button symbol)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780879/how-can-i-change-texts-in-the-dynamic-textfields-in-simplebutton-instance-button/2787121#2787121)

Unfortunately, `upButtonText` return as null. According to the debug, `upButton` has 3 children, so I tried `getChildAt([0-2])` to try and get the text but didn't happen. Also tried getting it by instance name, also no luck. Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others' information I first of all set the TLF text to Editable.

Then I used this code to get the String inside the button:

```
var upState:Sprite = Sprite(drawButton.upState);
var upText:String = TLFTextField(upState.getChildAt(2)).text;
```

and to change the text: `TLFTextField(upState.getChildAt(2)).text = "Paused";`

This definitely works, and is tested.

Thanks to user elekwent for the tips.

Comment: This is *painfully* inelegant. You have to grope at which child is your text until you find the right one, but it does the job. Also! You'll need to do the same thing for downState and overState if they have their own key frames. This is definitely a solution if you're working with Flash IDE buttons.

Comment: Indeed it is, but it was the only way to do it at the time. Also, yes the child positions in the display list hierarchy vary, so it requires experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
package
{
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class Test extends Sprite
    {
        public function Test()
        {
            var t:TextField = new TextField();
            t.text = "Play";
            var b:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton(t);
            addChild(b);
            trace(TextField(b.upState).text);
        }
    }
}
```

The trace output displays the text property of the TextField.

Your approach doesn't work because neither the SimpleButton nor TextField classes inherit from the DisplayObjectContainer class, and therefore cannot use the addChild(), addChildAt(), or getChildAt() methods.

Cast drawButton.upState to a TextField and you can access its text property like so:

```
TextField(drawButton.upState).text
```

Comment: Appreciate that... I realise it should be working, but it just isn't right now. The SimpleButton is created in the Flash Auth. tool, not programmatically, i.e. derived from the MainTimeline.

Comment: No, it rightfully shouldn't be working. I updated my answer to explain.

Comment: Ah right I see, thanks for that... Any clues on how it could be done? I could replace the button with a new one, but the button is specifically designed and want to use the one I have...

Comment: I've used: `var upText:TextField = TextField(drawButton.upState); upText.text = "Paused";` however it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: I'm testing it out as we speak.

Comment: Check out my answer below... I cast the DisplayObject to DisplayObjectContainer (Sprite) to access it's child properties.

Comment: The code in your last comment works for me. It makes me wonder if your SimpleButton.upState really is a TextField. Can you show the code for it? If not, you can test it like this `trace(b.upState is TextField);`. If it outputs true then it is a TextField and we'll keep working on it.

Comment: Elekwent you've helped me out man... the actual answer to my problem is below in my contribution to our little problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me when I was trying to add text to a SimpleButton:
http://snipplr.com/view/8980/as3-creating-a-simplebutton-with-dynamic-text/